# Use a hard disk with TV and laptop simultaneously

Tags: wireless-networking, hard-drive, usb, tv

We have a samsung TV and you can connect a USB hard disk to it for watching movies. I would like to have a hardisk that I can use at the same time with the TV and with my laptop.

I wonder therefore what would be the best option for doing this?

I heard something about a hard disk that can be connected via usb (from lacie) to the TV and operated via wireless from laptop simultaneously.

Would this option would be ok?  Or are there better disks from other vendors/better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [review](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/nas/nas-reviews/31082-lacie-network-space-2-reviewed) that states that the device cannot operate wirelessly **AND** in USB mode. You would have to choose which mode. Maybe you are better off looking into something like [Popcorn Hour](http://www.popcornhour.com/onlinestore/), which will allow you to connect to the device in different ways (FTP, mount etc). You can then connect your tv to the popcorn hour via f.ex. HDMI